# Hide Question Set Based of Radio Selection

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am brand new to this and just messing around trying to learn.

I am trying to create an option for stone based off what elevation a customer has chosen. Each elevation has 4 levels of stone that vary in price. Right now I am just trying to hide the option for stone on the elevations that have not been selected.

I got it working for 1 radio button but not all of them.

I have tried switching it over to get getbyclassname and currently was trying to queryselectorall.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

        function yesnoCheck() {
            if (document.querySelectorAll('yesCheck').checked) {
                document.querySelectorAll('ifYes', 'ifYes2', 'ifYes3').style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
            else document.querySelectorAll('ifYes', 'ifYes2', 'ifYes3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        
        }
      </script>
```

```html
<div>
              Elevation A <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name=yesno id=yesCheck> 
              <div class=ifYes style='visibility:hidden'>
                <h6>Stone price for Elevtion</h6>
                  <div class='stone' id='stoneElv_A'>
                    <input type="radio" name=StoneElv_A_Lvl1>
                    <lable>Level 1 Stone</lable>
                    <input type="radio" name=StoneElv_A_Lv2>
                    <lable>Level 2 Stone</lable>
                    <input type="radio" name=StoneElv_A_Lvl3>
                    <lable>Level 3 Stone</lable>
                    <input type="radio" name=StoneElv_A_Lvl4>
                    <lable>Level 4 Stone</lable>
                  </div> 
              </div>
              Elevation B <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name=yesno id=yesCheck2> 
              <div id=ifYes2 style='visibility:hidden'>
                <h6>Stone price for Elevtion</h6>
                  <div class='stone' id='stoneElv_B'>
                    <input type="radio" name=StoneElv_B_Lvl1>
                    <lable>Level 1 Stone</lable>
                    <input type="radio" name=StoneElv_B_Lvl2>
                    <lable>Level 2 Stone</lable>
                    <input type="radio" name=StoneElv_B_Lvl3>
                    <lable>Level 3 Stone</lable>
                    <input type="radio" name=StoneElv_B_Lvl4>
                    <lable>Level 4 Stone</lable>
                  </div> 
              </div>
              Elevation C <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name=yesno id=yesCheck3> 
              <div id=ifYes3 style='visibility:hidden'>
                <h6>Stone price for Elevtion</h6>
                  <div class='stone' id='stoneElv_C'>
                    <input type="radio" name=StoneElv_C_Lvl1>
                    <lable>Level 1 Stone</lable>
                    <input type="radio" name=StoneElv_C_Lvl2>
                    <lable>Level 2 Stone</lable>
                    <input type="radio" name=StoneElv_C_Lvl3>
                    <lable>Level 3 Stone</lable>
                    <input type="radio" name=StoneElv_C_Lvl4>
                    <lable>Level 4 Stone</lable>
                  </div> 
              </div>

          </div>
```

Comment: querySelectorAll returns a collection of the nodes with the given selector - it does not return just one (even if there is only one). You have to loop through them to check each one.

Comment: `<lable>` is invalid HTML. Which means it's displayed as regular text (inline content). Did you mean `<label>` or `<table>`?